# CATransaction completion block is called twice

Tags: swift, animation, completionhandler, catransaction

I am trying to make CABasicAnimation with a CATransaction, so I can have a Completion handler. It works fine but when I quit the view Controller and come back, the completion block is called twice : Once when the animation starts and once it finishes. I only want it at the end.

The weird thong is that when I quit it and come back a second time, the completion is called 3 times and so on...

```
func animate() {

            CATransaction.begin()

            Animation.toValue = 0
            Animation.duration = CFTimeInterval(timerChoosenTime)
            Animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
            Animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

            CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
                //Some cool stuff
            })

            object.add(Animation, forKey: "Animation")

            CATransaction.commit()
}
```

I think the program creates multiple CATransactions. The way to fix it would be to cancel the CATransaction but I found nothing about that online. Still, I am not sure. Please help me...

Comment: What if you remove the begin and commit calls?

Comment: The same thing happens, it runs once when the animation starts and once when it finishes. The only code related to it I have is CATransaction.setCompletionBlock.

Comment: Show enough context to reproduce. How is your function called? What does quit and come back mean? Try to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: The function is called when I click on the screen. The quit and come back is a segue that goes to another view controller. The animation is a timer that makes a sound when it finishes. To reproduce, you have to make the animation run once (then it works fine), use the segue and come back with a "back" button, run the animation once again and the sound is played once it starts and once it finishes (hope it is clear)

Comment: Try to imagine that no one else has this issue. So no one but you knows how to make the issue happen. We can’t help unless you show us how to do that. Can you post a small demo project?